# writing to a file from print statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print out the top 10 words from each cluster and I am struggling to save it to a file not sure how to save the content to the file without just built-in function. Here is my code. Could anyone please give suggestions. Thanks

Code:

```
l=['0','1','2','3','4']

for i in range(best_K):
    print(l[i],"Cluster top words:", end='')
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]: 
        word=vocab_frame.ix[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
        print(' %s' % word, end=',')
    print()
```

Tried 1:

```
In the text file i get <built-in function print>
l=['0','1','2','3','4']

order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1] 

for i in range(best_K):
    f = open("output.txt", "w")
    print(l[i],"Cluster top words:", end='')
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]: 
        word=vocab_frame.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
        print(' %s' % word, end=',')
        my_top=str(print)
        f.write(my_top)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `print` function actually handles this. Is there a reason you chose not to use a context manager to handle the setup/teardown of your file buffer?

```py
l=['0','1','2','3','4']

order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1] 

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(best_K):
        print(l[i], "Cluster top words:", end='', file=f)
        print(*[vocab_frame.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0] for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]], sep=',', file=f)
```

Comment: I get invalid syntax at for.

Comment: Apologies, try now, I had missed a `]`

Comment: It stores only words but not these statements '0 Cluster top words:1 Cluster top words:2' without this i wont know which cluster number was those words belong to. @hemmelig

Comment: add `file=f` to the first `print` statement - `print(l[i], "Cluster top words:", end="", file=f)`

Answer (score 2):

```
fp = open("test.txt",'a')

for i in range(best_K):
    print(l[i],"Cluster top words:", end='',, file=fp)
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        word=vocab_frame.ix[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
        print(' %s' % word, end=',', file=fp)
    print(file=fp)
```

Comment: I am printing out a for loop and in place of 'your random string' how do i fit my print statement?